# why azure virtual machines should be created in in the same resource group as the availability set

Tags: azure-availability-set

I am creating azure virtual machine within an availability set. While creating, I have created a new resource group. Doing so, I am not allowed to select availability set I created in different resource group.
why it is a requirement that virtual machines should be created in the same resource group as the availability set.